# NSURLRequest with App Level ProxyHost/ProxyPort Settings

Tags: ios, proxy, nsurlrequest

I'm looking for a way to use NSMutableURLRequest with app level proxyHost/Port settings, essentially a replacement for ASIHTTPRequest lib with proxyHost/proxyPort.  I've tried modifying the CFReadStream (from NSURLRequest HTTPBodyStream), but it SIGSEGs when setting the proxy settings.  I would rather not have to rewrite my app with CFNetworking, and it looks like AFNetwork lib doesn't include this feature yet either.

Has anyone successfully done this with NSMutableURLRequest?

Comment: Have you find any solutions for the same ? Thanks +1

Comment: So far I have resorted to using the old ASIHTTPRequest Lib. (Not the solution I really wanted).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real answer appears to be creating a custom NSURLProtocol.  Should be a straight forward derivation, and add the appropriate proxyHost/proxyPort to the request (along with any other values such as a customized User Agent string).  Then, supposedly, all requests will be routed through this custom protocol (including UIWebView requests..direct or derived).

relevant samples:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/CustomHTTPProtocol/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013653

http://eng.42go.com/customizing-uiwebview-requests-with-nsurlprotocol/

I'll post more when I have the thing operational.

Things of note with this implementation.

1. Initially started using CFNetworking as the "wedge" in my custom
   NSURLPRotocol, but quickly found I was rewriting the same code that
   was in ASIHTTPRequest.  So I just implemented the wedge with
   ASIHTTPRequest.
2. The items that are not documented well (or at all), is the
   interaction of UIWebView with NSURLProtocol callbacks, vs
   NSURLRequest/Conenction with NSURLProtocol.  Some Findings:

   - a) All dependent page resources are loaded automatically by UIWebView
     (which we knew), and they all go through NSURLProtocol, so it is an
     excellent place to put in code to modify all requests.
   - b) The UIWebView sets the Referer header.  On a redirect, the only
     way to get the UIWebView to update it's Referer from the original URL
     to the new redirect URL is with the `[[self client] URLProtocol:self
     wasRedirectedToRequest:redirectRequest
     redirectResponse:tmpHttpResponse];` callback.
   - c) when the above redirect callback is received by UIWebView, it
     generates a new NSURLRequest (essentially the one you sent back to
     it).  So if you have a wedge that likes to do the redirect
     internally, you have to cancel the Request that it attempts to make, 
     in favor of the new one from UIWebView.
3. You have to be careful with which callbacks you implement from ASIHTTPRequestDelegate.  e.g. implementing `didReceiveData` will disable the built in gzip processing.  `willRedirectToURL` disables most of the built in redirect processing (even if you call `[request redirectToURL:newURL];` as recommended in the comments).

Comment: can you share some code? I need to proxy my 3th party lib's http connections, and this is not that easy